# When doing / while doing

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, conjunctions

I am a little confused about using "when v-ing" and "while v-ing". When should I use "when v-ing" instead of "while v-ing" ?

> 1- Always keep some change with you. It’s useful ***when buying*** a
>   bus ticket.
>
> 2- Always keep some change with you. It’s useful ***while buying*** a
>   bus ticket. (The dictionary say this usage is wrong)
>
> 3- Be careful ***when crossing*** the road.
>
> 4- Be careful ***while crossing*** the road. (Is it correct to use while here? )
>
> 5- I used to read a book ***when using*** public transport.
>
> 6- I used to read a book ***while using*** public transport. (Again, is it correct to use while here?)

Answer (score 1):

"We can use **while** to talk about **two longer events** or activities happening **at the same time**" ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/as-when-or-while)).

You can use "while" only in the examples 6, and maybe 4, because only there you have *two longer* events happening at the same time. (I personally do not feel that crossing the road is a "long event," though). So, *both* events need to be longer, which means, they are happening in a *period* of time rather than in a *moment* of time. But you could also use "when," as in the example 5.

You can always use "when," but you can use "while" only for two longer events.

So, 1, 3, 4, 5 and 6 are correct, but 2 is not.

There's a very clear presentation of using when and while on [Grammar-Quizzes.com](https://www.grammar-quizzes.com/adv_whenwhile.html).

Comment: Thanks. I know that rule but I thought there might be something else to differentiate them. + I don't understand why "crossing" is not a long event.

Comment: But I see some sentences like: "Be careful while driving." . I don't think if we want to use "while", there must be two longer events.

Comment: I updated my answer. Driving is a long event, so being careful while driving is also a long event - they both happen in a _period_ of time. You could say that crossing the road is also a long event and say "be careful while crossing the road," but to me it does not sound well, because you cross the road "at once," - so it's not really a long event.

Comment: -1 The use of *while* has absolutely nothing to do with the length of an event, not even the length of an event in relation to another. I can knock a vase to the floor while sneezing—both of which take only seconds, and both of which start and end at the same time.

Comment: I mentioned the length as a "period" as opposed to a "moment," not the actual length. Different explanations of using when vs while exist - I found the two from the linked sites most convincing. Would you like to make your answer and explain it?

Comment: Expanding on this: "while" has more of a sense of "in the middle of".  You should be careful all the time, from the start, when crossing a road, not only at some point after you have started!